# How to compress the video before uploading to database using react native

Tags: react-native, video-processing, video-compression

This is my whole page code to get video using react native image picker and then compress it using react-native compressor if anyone has done this functionality make sure to help and if possible you can message me on instagram @mujtaba._2
I have found 2 libraries one is react-native-compressor and react-native-video-processing .
Issue that I am facing!

1. Can't setup the library even after following the docs correctly
2. Even I correctly placed the docs code in my android file the app doesn't build or even after building the video is not getting compressed

I think they should improve the docs or provide a better example

```
import React from 'react'
import { launchCamera, launchImageLibrary } from 'react-native-image-picker';
// import Video from 'react-native-video'
import { Video } from 'react-native-compressor';

const Addpost = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [cameraImg, setCameraImg] = React.useState(null)
  const [video, setVideo] = React.useState(null)
  console.log('this is video', video);
  const requestCameraPermission = async () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      try {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
          {
            title: 'Camera Permission',
            message: 'App needs camera permission',
          },
        );
        // If CAMERA Permission is granted
        return granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED;
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err);
        return false;
      }
    } else return true;
  };

  const requestExternalWritePermission = async () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      try {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
          {
            title: 'External Storage Write Permission',
            message: 'App needs write permission',
          },
        );
        // If WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Permission is granted
        return granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED;
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err);
        console.log('Write permission err', err);
      }
      return false;
    } else return true;
  };
  const bufferConfig = {
    minBufferMs: 3000,
    maxBufferMs: 6000,
    bufferForPlaybackMs: 1500,
    bufferForPlaybackAfterRebufferMs: 3000,
  };
  const chooseFile = () => {
    let options = {
      mediaType: 'video',
      maxWidth: 300,
      maxHeight: 550,
      quality: 1,
    };
    launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
      //   console.log('Response = ', response);

      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled camera picker');
        return;
      } else if (response.errorCode == 'camera_unavailable') {
        console.log('Camera not available on device');
        return;
      } else if (response.errorCode == 'permission') {
        console.log('Permission not satisfied');
        return;
      } else if (response.errorCode == 'others') {
        console.log(response.errorMessage);
        return;
      }
      setVideo(response);
    });
  };

  const captureImage = async () => {
    setCameraImg(null)
    setVideo(null)
    let options = {
      mediaType: 'video',
      maxWidth: 300,
      maxHeight: 550,
      allowsEditing: true,
      quality: 0,
      videoQuality: 'low',
      durationLimit: 10, //Video max duration in seconds
      saveToPhotos: false,
    };
    let isCameraPermitted = await requestCameraPermission();
    let isStoragePermitted = await requestExternalWritePermission();
    if (isCameraPermitted && isStoragePermitted) {
      launchCamera(options, (response) => {
        // console.log('Response = ', response);

        if (response.didCancel) {
          console.log('User cancelled camera picker');
          return;
        } else if (response.errorCode == 'camera_unavailable') {
          console.log('Camera not available on device');
          return;
        } else if (response.errorCode == 'permission') {
          console.log('Permission not satisfied');
          return;
        } else if (response.errorCode == 'others') {
          console.log(response.errorMessage);
          return;
        }
        // if(type=='video'){

        setVideo(response)
        // }
        // else
        // {setCameraImg(response)};
      });
    }
  };
  const gotoReels = () => {
    navigation.navigate('/Reels')
  }
  React.useEffect(() => {
    handleCompressVideo()
  }, [video])

  const handleCompressVideo = async () => {
    if (video) {
      try {
        const result = await Video.compress(video.uri, {
          compressionMethod: 'auto',
        }, (progress) => {
          console.log('Compression Progress:', progress);
          // Update progress if needed
        });

        console.log('Compressed Video:', result);
        // Handle the compressed video result as per your requirement
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Video Compression Error:', error);
        // Handle any errors during compression
      }
    } else {
      console.warn('No video selected. Please select a video to compress.');
    }
  };
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'stretch' }}>
        <View style={styles.imgContainer}>
          {cameraImg && <Image source={{ uri: cameraImg.assets[0].uri }} alt='Img' style={styles.cameraImg} />}
          {/* {video &&
            <Video
              useBuffer={true}
              bufferConfig={bufferConfig}
              source={{ uri: video.assets[0].uri }}
              autoplay
              repeat={true}
              resizeMode={'cover'}
              style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
              customStyles={{
                wrapper: {
                  width: '100%',
                  height: '100%',
                  paddingBottom: 10,
                },
                video: {
                  width: '100%',
                  height: "100%",
                },
                controls: {
                  display: 'none',
                },
                seekBarBackground: {
                  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                },
                seekBarProgress: {
                  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                },
              }} />
          } */}
        </View>
        <View style={styles.options}>
          <Text style={styles.retake} onPress={captureImage}>{video ? 'Retake' : 'Take'} video</Text>
          <Text style={styles.retake} onPress={chooseFile}>Select From File</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ padding: 18 }}>
          <Pressable onPress={gotoReels} style={[styles.button, { marginBottom: 20, }]}
            disabled={!video}
          ><Text style={[styles.btnText,]}>Continue</Text></Pressable>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

export default Addpost

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  cameraImg: {
    width: '100%',
    height: "100%",
  },
  imgContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  options: {
    padding: 18,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  retake: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: 'black',
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    padding: 14,
    width: '100%',
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginTop: 35,
  },
  btnText: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 14
  }
})
```